# How do i see real time deletion / insertion of data on realm browser using Sync?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, realm

i have created a schema and i am able to successfully write in the default realm file. But how do i see the changes as they happen in the Object server? Do i have to use Realm.Sync.session or any event handlers... any insight would be appreciated..

```
var realm = require('realm');

const testScema = {
  name: 'profile',
  properties: {
    name: { type: 'string' },
    age: { type: 'int' },
    sport: { type: 'string' }
  }
};

var credentials = {
  url: "http://10.10.10.231:9080",
  ip: "localhost",
  port: 9080,
  username: "kirtan@gmail.com",
  password: "password"
};

// realm.Sync.Session = {
//   config: {},
//   state: "active",
//   url: credentials.url,
//   user: credentials.username,
// };

var realmObj;
realm.Sync.User.login(
  credentials.url,
  credentials.username,
  credentials.password,
  (error, user) => {
    if(error)
      console.log("error connecting to database");
    else{
      console.log("connection successfull");
      // console.log("realm.defaultPath", realm.defaultPath);
      realmObj = new realm({schema: [testScema]})
      // realmObj.path = "/Users/yashwant/realm";
    }
});
```

a little bit of code if anyone wants to review. Folder structure for realm would also be useful if i want to keep my database activities in a different file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "see the changes". You can open the synced realm with the [Realm Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/realm-browser/id1007457278?mt=12). But it sounds like you want to subscribe to some sort of notification from the server, which is unfortunately not possible at the moment.

Comment: thanks for responding ! if you used the realmtask app which they bundle with the developer edition of realm then you would see that as we delete the task from the application the corresponding entry is also deleted from the ROS. how do i achieve that ? using session sync or what ? @KristianDupont

Comment: In your code above, the `realmObj` instance is a Realm that will automatically be synchronized with the ROS running at the URL you specified. Whenever you add, update or delete data from it, it will be changed correspondingly on the ROS -- immediately or as soon as a network connection is established.

Comment: Ohk. Thanks for getting back to me. I appreciate it very much :) a lil more help would be great.
What if i want to see those changes in my realm browser ? Right now i have to pull the realm file from my AVD and then view the changes. If i change something then to see these changes i have to pull the realm file again using adb pull. Anyway i can see it in real time ? @KristianDupont

Comment: You are welcome :-) The realm browser can connect to a synced realm by choosing "Open Realm URL" instead of a file. Simply connect it to your ROS and you can inspect everything as it happens.

Comment: thanks :) . I will try it and get back to you. If it does not work i might trouble you a bit more. haha.. @KristianDupont